# Travis build failing but local tests are ok

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

The tests on local are ok but Travis keeps generating a module not found error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/travis/build/sa-ma/WayFarer/SERVER/models/migrations/seeds'
```

I think it is referring to babel-node

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/sa-ma/WayFarer/node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js:234:23)
```

and I have no idea why

This is the log file [Log](https://travis-ci.org/sa-ma/WayFarer/jobs/552941971)

Comment: looks like it was just a one-off issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, mistakenly wrote the server folder in uppercase in my package.json